# attempting to create a unique url using php - syntax error

Tags: php, syntax

I'm attempting to create a unique URL for each event but i'm getting a syntax error, do you know what it is?

```
echo '<div class="event-list">' . $row['eventname'] . '<p>' . $row['eventdate'] . '<p>' . 
'<img class="events" src="' . $row['eventimage'] .'"alt="" />' . "<a 
href='event.php?eventid=" . $row('eventID'] . "'>" . $row['eventname'] . "</a>" . 
'</div>';
```

Comment: 1. What is the syntax error? 2. You shouldn't be echoing out HTML like this. PHP is an embedded language. Take advantage of it.

Answer (score 3):

`$row('eventID']`

That `(` should be a `[`

You should use an editor with syntax highlighting, and in the future if you need help with an error, POST THE ERROR.

This is a good time to use HEREDOC syntax. Also indent and space your code. If you can't even read it, there's a problem.

```
<?php
$str = <<<STRING
<div class="event-list">{$row['eventname']}
    <p>{$row['eventdate']}<p>
    <img class="events" src="{$row['eventimage']}" alt="" />
    <a href="event.php?eventid={$row['eventID']}">{$row['eventname']}</a>
 </div>
STRING;

echo $str;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help. i'm new to php - can you recommend an editor with syntax highlighting? I'm using dreamweaver and it only tells me the line that the error is on?

Answer (score 1):

A syntax error isn't really a coding issue, yet I'm prepared to take a punt that the error read something like *unexpected '('*
That's because you have this typo:

```
$row('eventID']
```

Which should've been

```
$row['eventID']//square bracked
```

Please note: SO isn't a debugger service. Debugging is something you have to *learn* if you want to code

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way, and nice indented HTML :

```
<div class="event-list">
    <?php echo $row['eventname'] ?>
    <p>
        <?php echo $row['eventdate'] ?>
    <p>
    <img class="events" src="<?php echo $row['eventimage'] ?>" alt="" />
    <a href="event.php?eventid=<?php echo $row['eventID'] ?>" > <?php echo $row['eventname'] ?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: even simpler would've been to use `<?= $row['eventimage'] ?>` :-}